# Can't ping github, even by IP address; can ping other sites

Tags: dns, ping, github

I have already read numerous threads on this but I haven't found an answer that works.

I'm trying to install something on my VPS and my attempt to clone from Github fails with error, "fatal: unable to access github... Couldn't connect to server"

Pinging github.com also fails.

nslookup github.com returns 140.82.113.3, which looks right based on pinging github from another machine, but pinging that IP address from my VPS gives me "Network is unreachable." I'm confused that I can't even directly ping the IP address.

My VPS can successfully ping lots of other random sites, just not github.

I've tried the basics like editing my resolv.conf (adding nameserver 8.8.8.8) and other suggestions I've found, but nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: hi @stillnotfamous what OS you're having issue on? Few things to check: (1) Is the system time correct? (2) Any entry for GitHub in: `cat /etc/hosts` (3) Please post result for `traceroute github.com`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. System time is correct. Traceroute gives the right address (140.82.113.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets but says network is unreachable. etc/hosts has entries for localhost (127.0.0.1), my VPS (127.0.1.1), and a few for ip6-loopback, localhost, mcastprefix, allnodes, allrouters.

Comment: You may want to confirm that your VPS provider has not been blocked by GitHub. There have been instances in the past where GitHub (and other companies) have blocked IP ranges due to ideological differences.

Comment: Nope, they say they don't block any services.

Comment: My VPS provider says that my VPS does not have an IPv4 address (only IPv6) and github requires IPv4, which I can buy at additional cost. Is that right? Sounds odd - I'm trying to install something by cloning from github, and I can't even ping github.

Comment: @stillnotfamous from this answer `https://serverfault.com/a/596637`; you can add public DNS64/NAT64-resolvers to your `/etc/resolv.conf`:

`nameserver 2001:67c:2b0::4
nameserver 2001:67c:2b0::6`

Comment: Thank you! Your comment steered me in the right direction - I was able to find an IPv6 proxy for github that worked. Now I just have to find one for Wordpress. For those with the same problem, check out Dan Win or TransIP proxies.